# Airflow DAGs are successful but tasks are not running

Tags: airflow

I am trying to run a sample Airflow DAG. The DAG status is successful, but tasks are not running. Can anyone help me understand why?

I've tried the following:

- changing the start date to past date
- restarting web server and scheduler

[image]

Here is my code:

```
import datetime as dt

from airflow import DAG
from airflow.operators.bash_operator import BashOperator
from airflow.operators.python_operator import PythonOperator
print('test1')
def greet():
    print('Writing in file')
    print('testing the dag')
    with open('/Users/abc/Documents/airflow_workspace/greet.txt', 'a+', encoding='utf8') as f:
        now = dt.datetime.now()
        t = now.strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M")
        f.write(str(t) + '\n')
    return 'Greeted'
def respond():
    return 'Greet Responded Again'

default_args = {
    'owner': 'airflow',
    'start_date': dt.datetime(2019, 3, 12, 10, 00, 00),
    'concurrency': 1,
    'retries': 0
}

with DAG('my_simple_dag',
         default_args=default_args,
         schedule_interval='*/10 * * * *',
         ) as dag:
    opr_hello = BashOperator(task_id='say_Hi',
                             bash_command='echo "Hi!!"')

    opr_greet = PythonOperator(task_id='greet',
                               python_callable=greet)
    opr_sleep = BashOperator(task_id='sleep_me',
                             bash_command='sleep 5')

    opr_respond = PythonOperator(task_id='respond',
                                 python_callable=respond)
print('test2')
opr_hello >> opr_greet >> opr_sleep >> opr_respond
```

Comment: Are these new dagruns or only past ones because of early start_date of the dag? If you wait for the next dagrun it does look like the others or runs successfully?

Comment: these are the new dagruns. actually it was working just fine. i changed the working directory of dag in my local machine by setting the AIRFLOW_HOME path to new location. after changing the path i am seeing this issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the `dag_id` from `my_different_dag` to different name, it will actually create a new DAG.
So assuming you configured airflow correctrly it should work now.